# MFC Collection Classes (CArray, etc.) Support for Move Semantics / Rvalue Reference

Tags: c++, collections, stl, mfc, rvalue-reference

We have a huge amount of legacy code that is built around MFC's generic collection classes (CArray, CMap, etc.).  I cannot seem to find the support in these classes for C++'s move semantics that exists in the STL.

Am I overlooking some idiom that makes rvalue reference semantics (something like `CArray<somestruct, somestruct &&>`) viable with MFC's generic collection classes, or are we going to need to switch over to STL if we want to use this feature?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Until Microsoft decides to implement that functionality (and when, or even *if*, that will happen if up for guessing), you have to use the standard C++ containers if you want it.

Comment: I find it reasonably easy to replace `CMap` with `std::unordered_map` and `CArray` with `vector` whenever I touch code that uses it.  You'll want to custom roll a `std::hash<CString>` that samples as often as `CMap` does (every 1+len/10 characters) and do 32 bit hashing to match performance (if you care).